# Change text of a dynamically created checkbox

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, event-handling

In C# Windows Forms, how do I add an event to change the checkbox's text when clicked?
My code calls the "criarCheckBox" when it needs to but I cant refer to it to add the action.

```
    public void criarCheckBox(String nome, String texto)
    {
        CheckBox box = new CheckBox();
        box.Name = nome;
        box.Text = texto;
        listaCheckBox.Add(box);
        box.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(checkBoxClick);
    }

    void checkBoxClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: Is this WinForms, WPF, Windows Phone, Windows Store App, Universal App? Guessing it must be winforms based on CheckedChanged event?

Comment: Yes, it's winForms! I forgot to add

Comment: In an event you can cast the sender. Outside can can either search in the controls list of the parent or, better, imo, keep a reference to it, maybe in a list...

Answer (score 0):

Use the sender parameter:

```
void checkBoxClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var checkBox = (CheckBox)sender;
    checkBox.Text = "Hello";
}
```